# java - Unexpected result in Regex match

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if each line is equal to "test". When I try to run the following code, I expect the result to be true, because every line is exactly "test". Yet, the result is false.

```
// Expected outcome:
// "test\ntest\ntest" - should match
// "test\nfoo\ntest" - should not match
// "test\ntesttest\ntest" - should not match

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^test$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("test\ntest");

System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // result is false
```

What am I missing here? Why is the result false?

Comment: As Joe said, your regex is only matching the single word "test" because it test on that the word test is the start of the line and the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Pattern.compile("^test$", Pattern.MULTILINE)`, you only ask the regex engine to match one single line to be equal to `test`. When using `Matcher#matches()`, you tell the regex engine to match the full string. Since your string is not equal to `test`, you will get `false` as the result.

To validate a string that contains lines that are all equal to `test`, you may use

```
Pattern.compile("^test(?:\\Rtest)*$")
```

In older Java versions, you will need to replace `\R` (any line break) with `\n` or `\r?\n`.

See [online demo](http://ideone.com/bULx3U):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^test(?:\\Rtest)*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("test\ntest");
System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // => true
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `Pattern.MULTILINE`, it's matching against the whole string `test\ntest`. But in your regex, you are specifying that the string should consist of only a single instance of `test`, since it's surrounded by the start and end anchors.

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern.MULTILINE` allows your regex to match `^` and `$` before and after a line separator, which isn't the default behaviour. The default is to match only on the beginning and end of the input.

However, if you use matches() it tries to match the the regex against the whole input text producing a false, because the input isn't equal to just `"test"`.

Although matches() doesn't work, you can use find() to find a subsequence of the input matching the regex. Because `^` and `$` match before and after `\n`, your pattern finds two subsequences.

But that's just my two cents.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^test$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("test\ntest");

System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // prints "false", the whole input doesn't match a single "test"

System.out.println(matcher.find());    // prints "true"
System.out.println(matcher.group());   // prints "test"

System.out.println(matcher.find());    // prints "true"
System.out.println(matcher.group());   // prints "test"

System.out.println(matcher.find());    // prints "false"
```

Comment: In that case, why would one ever use Pattern.MULTILINE for a matches() check?

Comment: @XLordalX you wouldn't. One uses find() to make sure each line in the same input begins or ends with a given pattern.